# Transfer data from pssession to host?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Basically my issue comes down to this, I need to run code on a remote server using the ServerManager Module, but return the output to the local shell.

Here is the code run on WKS01:

```
Enter-PsSession SVR01
Import-Module ServerManager
$Roles = @(Get-WindowsFeature | Where {$_.installed -eq $true})
```

Now I need to use the data in $Roles on WKS01. Is there a way to do this? Am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what -ArgumentList is for.

You can pass arguments to a remote session using this parameter.
Here is an example:

```
$procName = "powershell"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (get-content c:\scripts\servers.txt) `
   -ScriptBlock {param ($Name) Get-Process -Name $Name} `
   –ArgumentList $procName
```

Comment: Yep, Ravi's way is what you want. Your problem is that you're working interactively on the remote machine by using Enter-PSSession. If you want to get results back from a remote machine to the local machine, you need work interactively on the local machine.

Comment: Thanks, I actually decided to do this with WMI (Win32_ServerFeature, go figure), and the method that prompted this question was an UGLY hack.

Answer (score 2):

```
$rs = New-PSSession -ComputerName SVR01
$Roles = Invoke-Command -Session $rs -ScriptBlock {
      Get-WindowsFeature | Where { $_.Installed }
}
Remove-PSSession $rs
```

Comment: You should format your code samples to avoid scrollbars. It's very unpleasant. Let me fix that for you ;)

Comment: I marked this as a helpful answer because it is a clean way to do what I asked for.